# php code not running when placed in a function

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT tbTastingNote.*, translation, lang FROM tbTaste RIGHT JOIN tbTastingNote ON taste = value WHERE ID=\"" . $prodID . "\" AND lang=\"" . $viewLanguage . "\" AND tasteCat = \"cask\" ORDER BY priority;";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              // output data of each row
              echo '<p class="tastingNote">';
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tastingNote = strtoupper(emptyCheck($row["translation"], $row["value"]));
                if($row["priority"] == 1) {
                    echo '<span class="tastingNote" style="font-size:var(--fontLarge);">' . $tastingNote . '</span>' ;
                    
                    $tastingNotePic = imageCheck('/images/tasting/' . newClean($row["value"]) . '.png', '/images/tasting/barrel.png');
                    } else {
                    echo '<span class="tastingNote" style="font-size:var(--fontMedLarge);">, ' . $tastingNote . '</span>' ;
                    }
                
              }
            } else {
             
             //Do nothing
            }
            echo '</p>';
            $conn->close();
```

Which works perfectly fine. But when changed to this - just a function name and open/close brackets - it does nothing, and I'm at a loss as to why.

```
tastingNoteRun();   
function tastingNoteRun(){

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT tbTastingNote.*, translation, lang FROM tbTaste RIGHT JOIN tbTastingNote ON taste = value WHERE ID=\"" . $prodID . "\" AND lang=\"" . $viewLanguage . "\" AND tasteCat = \"cask\" ORDER BY priority;";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              // output data of each row
              echo '<p class="tastingNote">';
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tastingNote = strtoupper(emptyCheck($row["translation"], $row["value"]));
                if($row["priority"] == 1) {
                    echo '<span class="tastingNote" style="font-size:var(--fontLarge);">' . $tastingNote . '</span>' ;
                    
                    $tastingNotePic = imageCheck('/images/tasting/' . newClean($row["value"]) . '.png', '/images/tasting/barrel.png');
                    } else {
                    echo '<span class="tastingNote" style="font-size:var(--fontMedLarge);">, ' . $tastingNote . '</span>' ;
                    }
                
              }
            } else {
             
             //Do nothing
            }
            echo '</p>';
            $conn->close();
}
```

Is there a generic reason why putting a code in a function might not work (it seems to work perfectly well if I use that function name just for a simple echo command or similar), or something more complex to do with the nature of the code?

Comment: How do you expect your function to know the values of `$servername, $username, $password, $dbname`? (and `$prodId` etc. etc.)

Comment: You need to add arguments when calling `tastingNoteRun()` method. Also add the same arguments in `function tastingNoteRun()`, just like wht you did in `new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)`